# Showing Completeness of a Space

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces

1. Given $s\geq1$, $X$ is nonempty set and $d: X\times X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is $b_s$-pseudo metric on $X$ if for $x,y,z\in X$

i. $d(x,x)=0$

ii. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

iii. $d(x,y)\leq s[d(x,z)+d(z,y)]$

2. $F=\{d_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a family of $b_s$-pseudo metric.
3. i. a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is convergent-$F$ to $x\in X$ if for all positive $\varepsilon$ there exist $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$d_k(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$$
   for all $n\geq N_0$ and $d_k\in F$.

ii. a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is Cauchy-$F$ if for all positive $\varepsilon$ there exist $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$d_k(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon$$
for all $n,m\geq N_0$ and $d_k\in F$.

iii. $X$ is complete-$F$ if each of its Cauchy-$F$ sequence is convergent-$F$.

I have $X =C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ i.e. a set of all continuous function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and I also have $F=\{d_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $$d_k(x,y)=\max_{t\in[0,k]}(x(t)-y(t))^2$$
for all $x,y\in X$

How can I show that $X$ is complete-$F$? I can't find $N_0$ such that its Cauchy-$F$ sequence is convergent-$F$.

Comment: In order to help you start : take a cauchy-$F$ sequence $(x_n)_n$. For any $k$, for any $t \in [0,k]$, you can found that $(x_n(t))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space of real sequences, and by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, you have a limit which we can note $x_0(t) \in \mathbb{R}$. Now try to prove that this function $t \mapsto x_0(t)$ belongs to $X$ and that $(x_n)_n$ is convergent-$F$ toward $x_0$.

Comment: I get the first part. But I dont know how to prove function $x_0$ is in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$d_k$ are indeed $b_s$-pseudo metrics on $X$. $(i),(ii)$ being obvious while for $(iii)$ we have
\begin{align}
d_k(x,y)&=\max_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-y(t))^2\\
&=\max_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-z(t)+z(t)-y(t))^2\\
&\leq 2\max_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-z(t))^2+2\max_{t\in [0,k]}(z(t)-y(t))^2\\
&=2d_k(x,z)+2d_k(z,y)
\end{align}
where in the third step we used the inequality $2\alpha \beta \leq \alpha^2+\beta^2$. Hence, $d_k$ are indeed $\beta_s$-pseudo metrics with $s=2$. Now, suppose we have an $F-$Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ on $X$. Then, for $\epsilon>0$ we may find $N$ such that
$$\tag{1} d_k(x_n,x_m)=\max_{t\in [0,k]}(x_n(t)-x_m(t))^2<\epsilon$$
for every $n,m\geq N$. Fix some $t\geq 0$ and find $k\geq t$. Then, by $(1)$ we have
$$\tag{2}|x_n(t)-x_m(t)|\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}$$
for every $n,m\geq N$. This shows that $(x_n(t))$ is Cauchy sequence on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, it converges to some limit denoted by $x(t)$. I.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n(t)=x(t)$ for every $t\geq 0$. Letting $n\to \infty$ in $(2)$ and squaring we obtain
$$|x(t)-x_m(t)|^2\leq \epsilon$$
for all $m\geq N$ and every $t\in [0,k]$. Taking $\sup$ to the above inequality we obtain
$$\tag{3} \sup_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-x_m(t))^2\leq \epsilon$$
for every $m\geq N$ and $k$. Now using $(3)$ we  can show that $f$ is continuous. Let $t_0\geq 0$ and $\epsilon>0$. By $(3)$ we may find $m$ such that
$$\tag{4} \sup_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-x_m(t))^2<\epsilon^2$$
for every $k$. By continuity of $x_m$ at $t_0$ there is and $\delta>0$ such that $|x_m(t)-x_m(t_0)|<\epsilon$ for every $|t-t_0|<\delta$. Pick $k>t_0+\delta$. Then, using $(4)$ and the continuity of $x_m$, for every $|t-t_0|<\delta$ we have
\begin{align}
|x(t)-x(t_0)|\leq |x(t)-x_m(t)|+|x_m(t)-x_m(t_0)|+|x_m(t_0)-x(t)|\leq 3\epsilon
\end{align}
Hence, $x$ is continuous. Now, returning to $(3)$ by the continuity of $x$ we can substitute $\sup$ with $\max$. Hence, rewriting $(3)$ we've shown that for $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $d_k(x,x_m)\leq \epsilon$ for every $k$ and $m\geq N$. This shows that $x_m$ is convergent-$F$ to $x$.

Comment: how do you find a fix $m$ from (3) to (4) that holds for every $k$?

Comment: We have shown that $x_n(t)$ converges to some $x(t)$ for all $\geq 0$. By $(1)$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we find $N$ such that $d_k(x_n,x_m)=\max_{t\in [0,k]}(x_n(t)-x_m(t))^2<\epsilon$ for every $n,m\geq N$ and every $k$. Letting $n\to \infty$ we obtain, $\sup_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-x_m(t))^2\leq \epsilon$ for every $m\geq N$ and every $k$. Hence, for every $\epsilon>0$ we shown that we can find $N$ such that $\sup_{t\in [0,k]}(x(t)-x_m(t))^2<\epsilon$ for every $m\geq N$ and $k$. If you plug $\epsilon=\epsilon^2$ to this you find some $m$ such that $(4)$ holds independently of $k$.

Comment: By $(1)$, the value of $N$ depends on $k$, right? What does $x_n(t)$ converges to $x(t)$ do in showing that there's $N$ such that $(1)$ holds for every $k$?

Comment: I'm sorry if I ask something too basic, because I don't understand but I need to. 

Comment: No, its ok, dont say sorry. Nothing its too basic if you encounter it for the first time. Its normal to ask and this is the way to grasp the ideas faster. In $(1)$ the integer $N$ does not depend on $k$. We obtain $(1)$ from the definition of $x_n$ being $F-$cauchy. If you check again the definition $(ii)$ that you gave the proposition "and $d_k\in F$" means independently of $k$. Using $(1)$ now, we show that for fixed $t$ the sequence $(x_n(t))$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, hence it converges to some $x(t)$. Then, by keeping $m$ fixed and taking $n\to \infty$ we obtain $(3)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help ☺️